# iText7 how to add another pdf as background to exising pdf

Tags: itext7

I have 2 PDF files. **under** is single-page PDF file and must be a background for every page of **original**...
This is not working

```
        public static byte[] overlay(byte[] original, byte[] under)
        {
            using (var resultStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
            
                var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(resultStream);
                var pdfReader = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(original));
                var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);

                for (var p = 1; p <= pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages(); p++) 
                {
                    var pdfUnder = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(under)));
                    var pdfUnderPage = pdfUnder.GetFirstPage().CopyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);
                    var page = pdfDoc.GetPage(p);
                    var canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamBefore(),
                        page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
                    canvas.AddXObjectAt(pdfUnderPage, 0, 0);
                    pdfUnder.Close();

                }
            
                pdfDoc.Close();
                return resultStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: *"This is not working"* - what do you mean by that? Does it not compile? Does it compile but throw an exception? Does it not throw an exception but the output is not as expected? With some details, please.

Comment: It compile it works without exception but it outputs original document without overlay

Comment: Please share pdf files. That code should work unless pdfs. Are not usable.